# UI5 Tooling - Import existing Fiori Apps from ABAP to VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, sapui5, vscode-extensions, sap-fiori, ui5-tooling

Lately, I had to rush a change from a local SAP WebIDE to VSCode, for UI5 app development. I have 81 (and counting) UI5 applications, already running on production. There are always some additions and some bug fixes needed.

UI5 Tooling on VSCode is awesome, but I desperately need a practical way for importing existing Fiori apps from on-premise SAP NetWeaver Gateway to VSCode. Is there an easy way, or should I open the path and maybe develop another extension for that. I am used to do it at SAP WebIDE like this:

[image: app importing]

Comment: best practive: migrate everything to git. pulling and pushing changes directly from the SAP system is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I wish i work with people using git, or even knowing git, someday.. But now i don't have time, to teach every consultant i work with how to use git. Also i don't got resources to change the company architecture which is too old etc.

Thanks anyway for remembering me the dream environment :D

Comment: Download the bsp via [/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_snc700_ehp04/helpdata/de/a5/60bd6ed4654fd1b338df065d331872/content.htm?no_cache=true) or export it from webide as .zip and import it into vscode

Comment: If you have time to create a new extension then you might have time to introduce git ;) gitlab is free to use. I extended the http handler in SICF so only one user was allowed to deploy code. this user was then stored in gitlab. so everyone was forced to use the gitlab workflow.

Comment: @aitopcu there are many git repositories free of charge. Using a repository is a must not a good practice. By importing the app directly from the environment you are actually importing the distribution version which is most likely minified

Comment: And thank you @MrNajzs for just doing that. But that solution feels like too many manual steps. Maybe someone have developed some extension to automate that flow i wonder.

Comment: WebIDE/BTP comes with a basic git. Matter of 5 mins per app to create one. Then you can push/pulls from vscode and webide. Also the gateway system dose NOT contain all relevant files!